# Open link in a tab from chrome extension's iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a pop up extension for google chrome. I have added an `iframe` in that popup.  Now when i try to open a link from that `iframe`.. its not working.. its not even working within the iframe itself. i need the links in `iframe` to be opened in a new tab.

I tried writing some scripts which can change `href` in `a` to be opened in a new tab or in the same tab. But how to do that for an `iframe`.

Note: The page loaded in `iframe` is in my control and can be changed if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<base target="_blank"/>` into `<head>` of that iframe. You can also mark individual links with `target="_blank"`.

Comment: is there a way to do that with javascript..?

Comment: @Jeyanth If iframe is not part of your extension then I don't think there is a way.